# Using gcloud's credential helper to access Google Source Repositories prevents osxkeychain from working

Tags: git, gcloud, google-cloud-source-repos

In the [Google Source Repositories docs](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes), it asks you to use `git config credential.helper gcloud.sh` to allow Git to authenticate

Recently, that's prevented me from using osxkeychain auth with GitHub - after adding that command, I get this error message when I attempt to pull from GitHub (on a repo whose only remotes are GitHub remotes):

```
git pull 

remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/[].git/'
```

Note that it doesn't even ask for my username & password again; it immediately refuses to connect

If I remove the gcloud credential.helper from git config, I can re-authenticate with GitHub (though need to type my username & password in again)

I'm using `git version 2.15.1` and `gcloud`:

```
Google Cloud SDK 183.0.0
alpha 2017.09.15
beta 2017.09.15
bq 2.0.27
container-builder-local
core 2017.12.08
datalab 20171003
gcloud
gsutil 4.28
kubectl
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem here is that the instructions overwrite a possible existing credential helper. To restrict the credential helper to only apply to Google Source Repositories run:

```
git config credential.'https://source.developers.google.com'.helper gcloud.sh
```

or change in your .git/config

```
[credential]
        helper = gcloud.sh
```

to

```
[credential "https://source.developers.google.com"]
        helper = gcloud.sh
```

Comment: This looks great so far! 
...and even could be the answer in the docs

Answer (score 0):

You need to set credential helper for Google Cloud repository only, not system wide.

Also for github consider using ssh-keys instead of username/password: https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

Comment: How do you set it for the Google Cloud repo only? The default of `git config` is `--local` anyway, though it's a repo that has an origin on both GH & Google Cloud so needs to exist in `--local`

Comment: SSH is possible, though it's a hack around the issue, and prevents using a username & password for GitHub