# How can I do git push to github private project in GCP compute engine VM

Tags: git, github, google-cloud-platform

I am using GCP compute engine VM and VS code remote explorer SSH to the VM to write my code. How can I do git push/pull/add etc to GitHub private project inside the VM?

Comment: The same way you'd do them in a non-VM. You need ssh or https access to the GitHub repo, so that you can clone / fetch / push, and then you need to run Git commands. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTTPS, make sure to define a `git credential.helper` to cache your credentials (like git config --global credential.helper "cache --timeout=36000" for instance)

If you had `gcloud.sh` configured, make sure it is limited to GCP repositories as [documented here](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes), or that helper would [prevent you to access GitHub repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48835676/6309).

That is why using SSH might be more convenient in this case.